# Run Apache Isis Application on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-mars, isis

I just started learning Apache ISIS. I have configured the application and imported into Eclipse(Mars). Can anyone tell me how I can run the application from eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing you need to do is to set up the DataNucleus enhancer.  There's details and a screencast [here](http://isis.apache.org/guides/dg.html#_dg_ide_eclipse)

We have found that the DN enhancer can be a little unreliable on larger projects, which was one of the reasons as developers we ended up moving to using IntelliJ (community edition is fine).  YMMV.

Within an IDE you run the app using the org.apache.isis.WebServer helper class (it's just a wrapper around jetty).

HTH